# Getting Module Error when trying to import the Package I uploaded on PyPi

Tags: python

I created a new python package to return random facts. I went through all the steps and uploaded it to PyPi. Installed it with pip, and when I try to import it, I get the error, `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'randfacts'`. I'm not sure if I've nested the files incorrectly or if something like setup.py isn't correct, but I don't get errors when I run the main python file on its own. Here's my file nesting:

```
randfacts/
    randfacts/
        __init__.py
        randfacts.py
    test/
    LICENCE
    README.md
    setup.py
```

Here's the setup.py file:

```py
import setuptools

with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setuptools.setup(
    name="randfacts",
    version="0.0.3",
    author="Tabulate",
    author_email="tabulatejarl8@gmail.com",
    description="Package to generate random facts",
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url="https://github.com/TabulateJarl8/randfacts",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
    python_requires='>=3.6',
    install_requires=[
        "random",
        "json",
        "requests",
        "bs4",
        "logging",
    ],
)
```

Anyone got any idea of why I can't import it? Nothing on Google is really clear on anything past uploading the file. Tell me if you need more information.

Comment: is this your pypi package? https://pypi.org/project/randfacts/

Comment: Yes, I first uploaded it yesterday

Comment: I was able to install and can import the module. But if I try "from randfacts import randfacts" it blows up because my environment is missing "requests". I checked and the package in pypi doesn't have any dependencies listed there.

Comment: Hmm I wonder why I can't do it but you can, Ill add an install_requires section to my setup.py file too